# Group Query for oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a scenario where I need to fetch all the records within an ID for the one source along with other source. Given below is my input set of records.

```
ID  SOURCE  CURR_FLAG       TYPE
1   IBM       Y               P
1   IBM       Y               OF
1   IBM       Y               P
2   IBM       Y               P
2   TCS       Y               P
3   IBM     NULL              P
3   CTS     NULL              P
3   TCS     NULL              P
4   IBM     NULL              OF
4   CTS     NULL              OF
4   TCS      Y                ON
5   CTS     NULL              OF
5   TCS      Y                ON
```

From the above records, I need to select all the records with source as IBM within that same ID group and other source should be also there for the same ID along with IBM.Also, we need to fetch only those records where at least one record in that ID group with curr_fl='Y'

In the above scenario even though the ID=1 have a source as IBM, but there is no record in that particular group with other source.So we shouldn't fetch that record with that ID.
For the record  ID=3 have a source as IBM along with other sources, but there is no record with CURR_FL='Y', my query should not fetch the value.In the case of ID=4, it can fetch all the records with ID=4, as one of the records have value='Y' and it have a combination of IBM with other source.For ID 5 it should not fetch as we dont have any IBM record source within that set

Also within the group which has satisfied the above condition, I need one more condition for type. if there are records with type='P', then I need to fetch only that record.If there are no records with P, then I will search for type='OF' else type='ON'

My Expected output is given below

```
ID  SOURCE  CURR_FLAG       TYPE
2   IBM       Y               P
2   TCS       Y               P
4   IBM     NULL              OF
4   CTS     NULL              OF
4   TCS      Y                ON
```

I have written a query as given below.But it's running for long and not fetching any results. Is there any better way to modify this query

```
select
    ID,
    SOURCE,
    CURR_FL,
   TYPE
from TABLE a where 
  exists(select 1 from TABLE B where a.ID=B.ID and a.rowid<>B.rowid and B.source<>a.source)
  and exists(select 1 from TABLE C where a.ID=C.ID and C.source ='IBM')
and exists(select 1 from TABLE D where a.ID=D.ID and D.CURR_FL='Y') and
(TYPE,ID) IN (
select case  type when 1 then 'P' when 2 then 'OF' else 'ON' END TYPE,ID  from
(select ID,
     max(priority) keep (dense_rank first order by priority asc) as type
      from ( select ID,TYPE,
               case TYPE 
                     when 'P' then 1
                     when 'OF' then 2
                     when 'ON' then 3
                end as priority 
           from TABLE where ID 
            in(select ID from TABLE where CURR_FL='Y') AND SOURCE='IBM' 
                )
                group by ID))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, look for the `id`s.  I would recommend:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(source) <> max(source) and                            -- at least two sources
       sum(case when curr_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- at least one Y
       sum(case when source = 'IBM' then 1 else 0 end) > 0       -- IBM
```

To get the base rows, you can use `in`, `exists`, or `join`:

```
select t.*
from t
where id in (select id
             from t
             group by id
             having min(source) <> max(source) and                            -- at least two sources
                    sum(case when curr_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- at least one Y
                    sum(case when source = 'IBM' then 1 else 0 end) > 0       -- IBM
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using analytic functions you can check that there is at least one IBM in the group, at least one other source apart from IBM in the group, and at least one flag with Y in the group:

```
with t(id, source, curr_flag, type) as
(
  select 1, 'IBM', 'Y', 'P' from dual union all
  select 1, 'IBM', 'Y', 'OF' from dual union all
  select 1, 'IBM', 'Y', 'P' from dual union all
  select 2, 'IBM', 'Y', 'P' from dual union all
  select 2, 'TCS', 'Y', 'P' from dual union all
  select 3, 'IBM', NULL, 'P' from dual union all
  select 3, 'CTS', NULL, 'P' from dual union all
  select 3, 'TCS', NULL, 'P' from dual union all
  select 4, 'IBM', NULL, 'OF' from dual union all
  select 4, 'CTS', NULL, 'OF' from dual union all
  select 4, 'TCS', 'Y', 'ON' from dual union all
  select 5, 'CTS', NULL, 'OF' from dual union all
  select 5, 'TCS', 'Y', 'ON' from dual
)
select id, source, curr_flag, type
  from (select id, source, curr_flag, type,
               max(case when source = 'IBM' then 1 end) over (partition by id) ibm,
               max(case when source != 'IBM' then 1 end) over (partition by id) not_ibm,
               max(case when curr_flag = 'Y' then 1 end) over (partition by id) flag_y
          from t)
 where ibm = 1
   and not_ibm = 1
   and flag_y = 1
 order by id, source;
```